# Create new identifier column in data frame with values from the name of containing nested list

Tags: r

I would like to create a new identifier column in each data frame with values from the name of containing nested list.

```
parent <- list(
 a = list(
   foo = data.frame(first = c(1, 2, 3), second = c(4, 5, 6)),
 bar = data.frame(first = c(1, 2, 3), second = c(4, 5, 6)),
 puppy = data.frame(first = c(1, 2, 3), second = c(4, 5, 6))),
 b = list(
 foo = data.frame(first = c(1, 2, 3), second = c(4, 5, 6)),
 bar = data.frame(first = c(1, 2, 3), second = c(4, 5, 6)),
 puppy = data.frame(first = c(1, 2, 3), second = c(4, 5, 6))))
```

Therefore, the result for the first data frame in list a would look like this:

```
 > foo
    first second identifier
 1     1      4          a
 2     2      5          a
 3     3      6          a
```

The first data frame in list b would look like this:

```
 >foo   
    first second identifier
 1     1      4          b
 2     2      5          b
 3     3      6          b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you might want something like this

```
Map(function(name, list) {
  lapply(list, function(x) cbind(x, identifier=name))
}, names(parent), parent)
```

Here we use `Map()` and take the list and the names of the list and just `cbind` those identifiers into the data.frames.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `tidyverse`.  Loop through the `list` with `imap` (gives both the `values` as well as the `keys` (`name` of the `list`) as `.x` and `.y`, then with `map2`, loop through the inner `list` of data.frame and `mutate` to create the column 'identifier as `.y` aka the `names` of the `list`

```
library(tidyverse)
imap(parent, ~ map2(.x, .y, ~ .x %>%
                             mutate(identifier = .y)))
#$a
#$a$foo
#  first second identifier
#1     1      4          a
#2     2      5          a
#3     3      6          a

#$a$bar
#  first second identifier
#1     1      4          a
#2     2      5          a
#3     3      6          a

#$a$puppy
#  first second identifier
#1     1      4          a
#2     2      5          a
#3     3      6          a


#$b
#$b$foo
#  first second identifier
#1     1      4          b
#2     2      5          b
#3     3      6          b

#$b$bar
#  first second identifier
#1     1      4          b
#2     2      5          b
#3     3      6          b

#$b$puppy
#  first second identifier
#1     1      4          b
#2     2      5          b
#3     3      6          b
```

---

If we want to have the column based on the data.frame name, loop through just the `list` elements with `map`, then use `imap` to loop through the inner `list` so as to get the `key`s (`names` of the inner `list`) and create a new column 'identifier

```
map(parent, ~ imap(.x,  ~ .x %>%
                       mutate(identifier = .y)))
```

Comment: How would your solution be changed to add a column with the value of the data frame name?  I am new to tidyverse.

Comment: @Srizza  Updated the answer.  I hope that is what you wanted

Comment: Yes your solutions are great.  I just wanted to learn a little more on how it works.